# Joining dataframes with different but consistent strings in R

Tags: r

I have been struggling with a join between two dataframes X & Y
X is a series of industries, with their subindustries and dollars spent there,
Y is an index of the same industries and sub industries matched to a code:

```
IND<- c("Ag", "Ag", "Total Ag", "Min", "Min", "Min", "Total Min")
SubIND<- c("agriculture", "aquaculture", "Total", "gold", "copper", "zinc", "Total")
Dollars<-sample(1:100,7)
INDcode<-c("A","B","C","D","E","G","H","M","R","Y","Z")
INDi<-c("Ag","Bar","Car","Don","Ec","Gl","Hu","Min","Run","Yt","Zal")

X <- data.frame(IND,SubIND,Dollars)
Y <- data.frame(INDi,INDcode)
join<-left_join(X,Y,by=join_by(IND==INDi))

       IND      SubIND Dollars INDcode
1        Ag agriculture       4       A
2        Ag aquaculture      63       A
3  Total Ag       Total      35    <NA>
4       Min        gold      68       M
5       Min      copper      14       M
6       Min        zinc      80       M
7 Total Min       Total      48    <NA>
```

"Total" pops up all through the dataframe and I want to know if there is a way for me to join so that e.g. "Min" and "Total Min" both end up with the INDcode "M"

My df has few enough of these that I can actually just do it by hand, or do a sum for each code and replace the total rows entirely, but was wondering if anyone had any ideas for how to do it better?

I have been looking at the fuzzyjoin package but cannot work out how to make it work for this task!

Thanks!

Comment: The simplest thing would be to strip `"Total "` from `IND`, eg `X %>% mutate(IND = str_remove(IND, "Total ")) %>% left_join(Y, join_by(IND == INDi))`. If you want to keep `IND` as-is, then make a helper column with `"Total "` removed to use as the key.

Comment: Somewhat agree with @zephryl comment, you are doubling down on `Total` in your columns. In general, during data cleaning, this should have been dealt with already (if following a good data mining/analysis praxis).

Comment: Thanks both, this is what I ended up doing in fact. I get sent a lot of dataframes like this with totals already calculated and added and was just hoping to see if there were any shortcuts that I could apply in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do a `fuzzy` join:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
IND <- c("Ag", "Ag", "Total Ag", "Min", "Min", "Min", "Total Min")
SubIND <- c("agriculture", "aquaculture", "Total", "gold", "copper", "zinc", "Total")
Dollars <- sample(1:100,7)
INDcode <- c("A","B","C","D","E","G","H","M","R","Y","Z")
INDi <- c("Ag","Bar","Car","Don","Ec","Gl","Hu","Min","Run","Yt","Zal")

X <- data.frame(IND, SubIND, Dollars)
Y <- data.frame(INDi, INDcode)
join <- fuzzy_left_join(X, Y, by = dplyr::join_by(IND == INDi), match_fun = stringr::str_detect)
join
#>         IND      SubIND Dollars INDi INDcode
#> 1        Ag agriculture      20   Ag       A
#> 2        Ag aquaculture      99   Ag       A
#> 3  Total Ag       Total      35   Ag       A
#> 4       Min        gold      64  Min       M
#> 5       Min      copper      23  Min       M
#> 6       Min        zinc      98  Min       M
#> 7 Total Min       Total       5  Min       M
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>